# Session Tracking?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am a newbie to java servlets and infact in a learning stage.. I am facing difficulty in sending my JSP page fields value to another page that is in short facing problems in session maintainance.. Kindly Help me getting the value across the whole session by giving some idea using simple constructive example to get a good understanding of the session use..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are JSPs that demonstrates the session tracking mechanism. Try clicking on the links on the page with and without cookies enabled in your browser. You should be able to maintain a session by the use of cookies or by encoding the URL. Disabling session cookies is done easily in Chrome.

```
<%
  String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
  String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
  String path = contextPath + servletPath;
  String encoded = response.encodeURL(path);
  Integer count = (Integer)session.getAttribute("count");
  if(count==null)count = new Integer(0);
  session.setAttribute("count",new Integer(count.intValue() + 1));
%>
sessionId=<%=session.getId()%><br/>
isNew=<%=session.isNew()%><br/>
fromURL=<%=request.isRequestedSessionIdFromURL()%><br/>
fromCookie=<%=request.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie()%><br/>
path=<%=path%><br/>
encoded=<%=encoded%><br/>
<a href="<%=path%>">Not encoded request</a><br/>
<a href="<%=encoded%>">Encoded request</a><br/>
count=<%=count%>
```

The above page works in any JSP container. If you using a new one(I tested with Apache Tomcat/7.0.28), then you can use the following page.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="session" />
<c:set var="relativePath" value="${fn:substringAfter(pageContext.request.servletPath, '/')}" />
The session id is ${pageContext.session.id}<br/>
Is the session new ? ${pageContext.session['new']}<br/>
Did the client send the session id in the URL ?   ${pageContext.request.requestedSessionIdFromURL}<br/>
Did the client send the session id in a cookie ?   ${pageContext.request.requestedSessionIdFromCookie}<br/>
<a href="${relativePath}">Not encoded request</a><br/>
<a href="${pageContext.response.encodeURL(relativePath)}">Encoded request</a><br/>
Count is ${count}
```

Comment: (With the caveat that normally you're never do this kind of work with scriptlets.)

Comment: @DaveNewton This is just a demonstration page.

Comment: I understand, but it's important to point out that it's horrible.

Comment: Because saying "In normal code, scriptlets wouldn't be used, Java code would be in Java files, and you'd use JSP EL and/or JSTL" isn't an answer to the question, and should be assumed in this era.

Comment: @DaveNewton Please see my lastest edition. See no scriptlets! I finally joined the modern era(with your prodding). But, I still like the old code better. I started using JSP in Tomcat 3.2.

Comment: Oh, nicer. Although much of that `pageContext` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know what you mean by that. It seems to me that the pageContext is necessary for reference to the request and the session objects.

Comment: Not at all. Both `session` and `request` are available on every page without `pageContext`. What's more, you don't even *need* to specify an explicit scope, although you may--JSP EL will search scopes until it finds the value.

Comment: (And you do so yourself when you write `${count}` at the bottom--that's a session attribute.)

Comment: @DaveNewton I think you are confusing the session object(the session object for the client) with the sessionScope object(maps session-scoped variable names to their values).

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Yep, you're right. The objects themselves are never needed in a reasonable JSP page, which is why they're not exposed directly.